# Node js: Call internal function in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a module that needs to call internal functions within the module and make use of variables in the constructor. To call these functions internally I could either use the variable `mycode` or use the keyword `this`. However using `mycode` means using a global variable and `this` can be overwritten by parts of my functions. This is a simplified model of my module's structure:

```
// app.js
const MyCode = require('mycode.js');
var mycode = new MyCode();
mycode.function1($(html));

// mycode.js
module.exports = class {
    constructor() {
        this.alertUrl = true;
    }

    function1(html) { 
        html.find('a').each(function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            this.function2(url); // this is now overridden by jquery
        });
    }
    function2(url) { if (this.alertUrl) alert(url); }
}
```

I am looking for a solution that would work like `myModule.function2(url);`, where `myModule` is only available to functions inside the module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arrow function instead, so that the `this` reference is inherited from the outer scope, rather than being altered by the `each` callback:

```
html.find('a').each((_, elm) => {
  var url = $(elm).attr('href');
  this.function2(url);
});
```

Another (less elegant) option is to save a reference to the instance before calling the `each`:

```
function1(html) {
  var self = this;
  html.find('a').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    self.function2(url);
  });
}
```

The problem doesn't really have anything to do with modules, just the calling context of functions.

Comment: I'm not concerned with `this.alertUrl` being overwritten, I'm trying to make sure I can reference it and my functions from within another module.exports function. I.e., The `this` in `this.function2(url)` is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async function with export like this:

```
const function_name = async () => {
};

export default function_name ;
```